# Is it possible to create a window without using a NIB file on iPhone and OS X?

Tags: c#, iphone, cocoa, delphi, delphi-prism

Comming from a purely Win32/Delphi background I am somewhat puzzled by my new Mac-centric environment. I have been looking for examples of how to open a Window from code only (C# or Delphi Prism), without using a NIB file. Sadly I find little on this subject. Every example I find makes use of the Interface Builder exclusively.

Surely there must be an API call for this somewhere?
Or at the very least, being able to construct a NIB at runtime and load from memory?

Comment: afaik you can't write iphone applications in c#. You have to use objective c. If you use XCode then you can start a "window based project" and everything is done for you. I can't see the need to create a window outside of this.

Comment: You can use MonoTouch (see http://monotouch.net/) to create iPhone apps in C# and any .NET language. The need is to avoid the overhead of MVC programming where you want to use components comming from an event driven ad-hoc environment (like Delphi on Windows).

Comment: You can also create native iPhone apps using FreePascal's Arm compiler (http://wiki.freepascal.org/iPhone/iPod_development), it even links to X-Code with pre-made templates. The problem is wrapping the operative system's calls in proper classes. I just find it strange that MVC is enforced when Apple typically allows for a middle-way everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/kicking-off-iphone-development) might be a good start. It creates a green Window on an iPhone (but can be used on an iPad as well).
It uses Objective-C using the cocoa framework, not C#/Delphi/.NET.
So you will need to find a way to translate that to your .NET language of preference.

--jeroen

Comment: Found it, it was wrapped in one of the constructors: UIWindow myWindow = new UIWindow(screen.Frame); The Native Call (i.e from FreePascal is CreateWindowFromFrame(Const aRect:PRect); Funny how I didnt find this before. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Let me know (by email) how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write iphone programs with C# but with Objective-C. 
Instead of using interface builder, you can create your main UI by hand. The main function to create a view (Window, label, Button etc) in iOS is to use the function CGRectMake.

> CGRectMake Returns a rectangle with the specified coordinate and size
>   values. 
>   CGRect CGRectMake (    CGFloat x, CGFloat y,    CGFloat width, CGFloat height );

For instance, to create a window, you can do this :

```
UIWindow * window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)];
```

Or for creating a label, you can also do this :

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)];
```

You only have to specify the width, the height and the position of your view.

You can go on apple developper page for more details, specially this one : http://bit.ly/eZpDoC

Sorry if I wasn't clear before ;)

Comment: See my comments above, you can use both MonoTouch and freepascal for native iPhone development. Creating Views is easy enough, but it's the window object and enforced "nib" file use im concerned with.

Comment: Also, CGRectMake creates a rectangle structure (TRect in Delphi) - not a window object. A Mac app has some default objects, like Application, First responder etc. (and typically a window object that have X number of View decendants on it). I want to drop the use of Interface builder all together and call the Widget server directly.

Comment: If you go and read in my link, you will see that creating a window with that function is very simple : window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease]; This is the way i program, i never use the Interface builder

Comment: Excellent, thank you. You should update your comment, it looks like you are responding with create-rect :)

Comment: @Dimitri the problem is that CGRectMake doesn't create a window, label  or button etc as you stated.